# Is there any harm in having PRINT statements in (production) SP's?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there any harm at all in having PRINT statements in stored procedures, even in production? I have some primitive PRINT debugging statements in a huge SP enclosed by a IF @debug = 1 parameter such as this:

```
IF(@debug = 1) PRINT 'Some debug info'
```

When I exec the SP with @debug = 1 through SSMS, the debug statment(s) will print.

Can anyone think of anything harmful from having a reasonable amount of debugging PRINT statements in production code, assuming the SP is shielded behind numerous layers of firewall, service authentication, SQL server authentication, and so on?

Comment: You dont run sps in debug mode in prod. There is no harm.

Comment: You may find the `RAISERROR` statement more useful in debugging than `PRINT` for a variety of reasons.  A great article by Jim McLeod on this can be found [here](http://www.jimmcleod.net/blog/index.php/2010/07/19/print-vs-raiserror/) if you're interested.

Comment: Presumably, there is technically some small performance hit for checking whether `@debug = 1` is true or false. However, outside of realtime environments where you're trying to pare nanoseconds off your run time, this should be negligible, and ignorable.